# Is there a numpy function to replace one array with the same part of another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two images stored as numpy arrays. I am looking for a function that can replace the parts of `array2` that have black pixels (`[0, 0, 0]`) with the same indices of `array1`. My code so far is non-numpy:

```py
for y in range(array2.shape[0]):
            for x in range(array2.shape[1]):
                if np.all(array2[y, x]) == False:
                    array2[y, x] = array1[y, x]
```

The code loops over every pixel in `array2` to see if all of the channels are 0 (black), and if so copies the colour of `array1` at that index onto `array2`.

This is obviously very slow because it loops over a lot of pixels that aren't black and has no affect on them. I assume numpy has a function that can do this, but I can't understand what they do. Any guidance (with or without numpy) is appreciated.

Comment: could you please add a minimal example for `array2` and `array1`? at least to have matching `.shape`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something like you want? (I assume that there are no negative values.) (Edit: but see comment by Adam.Er8 to lift this limitation)

```
>>> arr1                                                                                                                                             
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6]],

       [[7, 7, 7],
        [8, 8, 8],
        [9, 9, 9]]])
>>> arr2
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
>>> idx = arr2.sum(axis=2) == 0
>>> idx
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True]])
>>> arr2[idx] = arr1[idx]
>>> arr2
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [6, 6, 6]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [8, 8, 8],
        [9, 9, 9]]])
```

Comment: great answer! note: you can use `idx = (arr2 == 0).all(axis=1)` and not rely on sum and non-negative values.

Comment: Close, but I am looking for every zero in `arr2` to be replaced with its value in `arr1`, not just the lines that are only zeros.

Comment: @incarnadine you probably have a 3d array, which is a matrix of `[R,G,B]` pixels, which is exactly what's described in this answer.

Comment: @incarnadine that's what you've described in the question: you want black pixels (triples of 0) to be replaced, not every 0. For every 0 it's even simpler, just use `idx = arr2 == 0`.

Comment: Sorry, I now understand your answer. Using your solution, I get an error `IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 640 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3` as `idx` is `(480, 3)`, but `arr2` is `(480, 640, 3)`

Comment: Well, check your array shapes and how do you store data inside. The shape of `idx` should be the same as the dimensions of the image.

Comment: @incarnadine Ah, sorry, I have a typo, it should be `axis=2`, will fix now. I cannot count to 3, apparently :)

Comment: @avysk and it gave the same answer! lol! subtle bugs >_<

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.copyto`:

```
from scipy.misc import face
from PIL import Image
 
img = face()
out = np.random.randint(-1000,256,img.shape).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

Image.fromarray(out).show()

np.copyto(out,img,where=(out==0).all(axis=-1,keepdims=True))

Image.fromarray(out).show()
```